# Rounding up for a Graph Maximum

Tags: c#, math

I'm graphing some statistics which can be percentages, currency values or plain numbers.

I need to set the maximum value of the graph control's axis to a nice, round number just a bit above the maximum value in the data set. (The graph control's default value is not what I want).

Two things to note:

1. The value I set for the axis maximum should be minimum 5% above the dataset's maximum value (the less above this the better).
2. I have 4 horizontal lines above the 0 Y-axis; so ideally the Y-axis maximum should divide nicely by 4.

Sample data might be:

```
200%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 75%, 50%, 9%
```

In this case, 220% would be acceptable as the maximum value.

```
$3500161, $1825223, $1671232, $110112
```

In this case, $3680000 might be ok. Or $3700000 I suppose.

Can anyone suggest  a nice formula for doing this? I might need to adjust settings, like the 5% margin might be changed to 10%, or I might need to change the 4 horizontal lines to 5.

Comment: Why is this labelled SQL?  You would do this in the C# code used to generate the graph.

Comment: sql tag has been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I use to create graph axes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Axis scales a min/max value appropriately for the purpose of graphs
/// <remarks>Code taken and modified from http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/calculate-nice-axis-scales-in-excel-vba/</remarks>
/// </summary>
public struct Axis 
{
    public readonly float min_value;
    public readonly float max_value;
    public readonly float major_step;
    public readonly float minor_step;
    public readonly int major_count;
    public readonly int minor_count;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Axis from range of values. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x_min">Low end of range to be included</param>
    /// <param name="x_max">High end of range to be included</param>
    public Axis(float x_min, float x_max)
    {
        //Check if the max and min are the same
        if(x_min==x_max)
        {
            x_max*=1.01f;
            x_min/=1.01f;
        }
        //Check if dMax is bigger than dMin - swap them if not
        if(x_max<x_min)
        {
            float temp = x_min;
            x_min = x_max;
            x_max = temp;
        }

        //Make dMax a little bigger and dMin a little smaller (by 1% of their difference)
        float delta=(x_max-x_min)/2;
        float  x_mid=(x_max+x_min)/2;

        x_max=x_mid+1.01f*delta;
        x_min=x_mid-1.01f*delta;

        //What if they are both 0?
        if(x_max==0&&x_min==0)
        {
            x_max=1;
        }

        //This bit rounds the maximum and minimum values to reasonable values
        //to chart.  If not done, the axis numbers will look very silly
        //Find the range of values covered
        double pwr=Math.Log(x_max-x_min)/Math.Log(10);
        double scl=Math.Pow(10, pwr-Math.Floor(pwr));
        //Find the scaling factor
        if(scl>0&&scl<=2.5)
        {
            major_step=0.2f;
            minor_step=0.05f;
        }
        else if(scl>2.5&&scl<5)
        {
            major_step=0.5f;
            minor_step=0.1f;
        }
        else if(scl>5&&scl<7.5)
        {
            major_step=1f;
            minor_step=0.2f;
        }
        else
        {
            major_step=2f;
            minor_step=0.5f;
        }
        this.major_step=(float)(Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(pwr))*major_step);
        this.minor_step=(float)(Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(pwr))*minor_step);
        this.major_count=(int)Math.Ceiling((x_max-x_min)/major_step);
        this.minor_count=(int)Math.Ceiling((x_max-x_min)/minor_step);
        int i_1=(int)Math.Floor(x_min/major_step);
        int i_2=(int)Math.Ceiling(x_max/major_step);
        this.min_value=i_1*major_step;
        this.max_value=i_2*major_step;
    }
    public float[] MajorRange
    {
        get
        {
            float[] res=new float[major_count+1];
            for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
            {
                res[i]=min_value+major_step*i;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    public float[] MinorRange
    {
        get
        {
            float[] res=new float[minor_count+1];
            for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
            {
                res[i]=min_value+minor_step*i;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

You can the nice `max_value` and `min_value` as calculated from the initialized for `Axis` given the mathematical min. max. values in `x_min` and `x_max`.

**Example:**

1. `new Axis(0,3500161)` calculates `max_value = 4000000.0`
2. `new Axis(0,1825223)` calculates `max_value = 2000000.0`
3. `new Axis(0,1671232)` calculates `max_value = 1800000.0`
4. `new Axis(0, 110112)` calculates `max_value =  120000.0`

Comment: Yep, i think that's roughly what I need, although I don't fully follow the math yet! I'll have to modify it a bit to get the gap a bit lower. But thanks!

Comment: The only part I am missing here is forcing the graph to isometric scaling. I would need to size the graph in pixels to do this to commonize the dpi between _x_ and _y_.

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st query use:

```
DataView data = new DataView(dt);
string strTarget = dt.Compute("MAX(target)", string.Empty).ToString();// target is your column name.
int tTarget = int.Parse(strTarget.Equals("") ? "0" : strTarget); // Just in case if your string is empty.
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(tTarget * 1.1); // This will give a 10% plus to max value.
```

For the 2nd point, i guess you can figure this out with minor/major axis interlaced and offset properties.

Comment: The chart control will automatically set the spacings between min/max of the Y axis to be exactly one-quarter (if you specify 4). Hence the need to find a number that divides by 4 "nicely" - that part I have to do myself (if I don't like their auto-generated choice).

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to decide on a range for (top of graph)/(max data point). You have this bounded on the lower end as 1.05; reasonable upper bounds might be 1.1 or 1.15. The wider the range, the more empty space may appear at the top of the graph, but the "nicer" the numbers may be. Alternatively, you can pick a "niceness" criterion first and then pick the smallest sufficiently nice number where the above ratio is at least 1.05.

You can also improve the "niceness" of the intervals by loosening that lower bound, for instance lowering it to 1.02 or even 1.0.

EDIT: In response to comment.

What you'll have to do to find a good max size is take your max value plus margin, divide it by the number of intervals, round it upward to the nearest "nice" value, and multiply by the number of intervals. A reasonable definition of "nice" might be "multiple of `10^(floor(log_10(max value)) - 2)`" A looser definition of niceness will give you (on average) less extra margin at the top.

Comment: The reason I say 5% is because that should make enough space for the bar label to fit above the bar. Otherwise the control places it ON the bar. So it needs to be in the 5-10% range. In fact, I've just tried 5% exactly and that isn't enough (just!). Still not sure how to get the nice round number above that though...